# Too much data on the XAxis to show all the bars Stacked Bar Chart JavaFx

Tags: javafx

I would like to display a Stacked Bar Chart in JavaFx, but the range of the Data is [0-256], so when I display the Chart, all the bars are not displayed.
I split the Chart with 3 parts parts :
[image: 3 parts]

I wonder if there is a better solution to display in one Chart all the data.

Comment: This seems more like a data visualization question than a JavaFX question. Consider perhaps using a `LineChart` instead of a bar chart. Or bin the data into groups of some reasonable number (8?) and show the average over each bin. You need to think about what knowledge you want the user to get from looking at the chart, and find the visualization that best achieves that, balancing detail with usability.

Comment: Ok, I think i will bin the data into groups as you said.Thanks